# Restore default user data in Google Chome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions

I normally used Chrome without signing in. Today, I decided to sign in to sync my bookmarks with my Google account. Then I decided to sign out to use Chrome without a Google account but discovered that only way to do it is to remove the account from the browser. Then I did it but saw that all my history, extensions, data of my extensions were gone. It was as if I removed and reinstalled the Chrome. My question is:

1) Are my initial data gone for good?

2) If not, is it synced with my Google Account? If so, is there a way to import this data to Chrome in order to use the Chrome without signing in?

3) If my initial data still resides in my computer, how can I revert the Chrome to the initial state? (State when I did not sign in for the first time)

Comment: So when I logged in to my account initially, it transferred default user's whole data to the account I logged in with? Is that right?

Comment: I mean, before I logged in, I was able to use chrome, with my data being stored locally and it was permanent when I quited the chrome. Now is it possible that somehow I regain that data to local and make it stay that way, so that I will be able to use chrome without signing in to a google account?

Comment: Thanks but how exactly I do it? Is it simply like this: When I log in, data is already downloaded to local. All I have to do is to copy is to somewhere else, so that I will have a copy of it when I log out (because I guess the original downloaded will be deleted). Then I move the data I copied to default user profile. Is that right?

Comment: I asked how to do what you said. You said download the data but how do I do it?

Comment: And is it downloaded automatically when I do it?